# How can I achieve where NOT IN in elastic search 6.x

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I achieve 
`where NOT IN`
in elastic search 6.x.
My mapping contains a field 'user_id'
I only want to fetch only those documents without certain users.

Comment: Did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here would lie in the [BooleanQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). This query type allows you to create a string of boolean operations that you use to search your data. In this case, you may want to look at the `must_not` clause.

More specifically to your question, what you would want to do is create a `must_not` clause where you userIds are in a [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) condition. E.G.:

```
{
   "query" : {
     "bool" : {
        "must_not" : {
            "terms" : {
               "user_id" : [<user_id_1>, <other_user_ids..>]
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the value placeholder below for whatever value you don't want.

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "user_id": {
              "value": "{ID_YOU_DONT_WANT}"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```